# python-tkinter: Is there any way to use image as active background

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to put an active background image, then the image button pressed it have to show brighten image on release it have be normal

```
from tkinter import *

tk=Tk()

def command():
    pass

image=PhotoImage(file='click.png')

image1=PhotoImage(file='click(bright).png')

button=Button(tk, image=image, command=command)
button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```